# Error in firestore - Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Accounts/YZnOaRYqjbZqzmT4oYIuNSTVgXU2 has 2

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save a document to firestore. I have created the following code and it works when the ID is removed and saves a document to the collection. But the problem is, I want the ID to save along with the document rather than creating a new one as I am trying to ensure the auth ID from the account creation and the document ID match.

This is my code and it appears to throw an error when ran - Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Support Network Member Accounts/YZnOaRYqjbZqzmT4oYIuNSTVgXU2 has 2.

```
   createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
          .then(async (cred) => {
            console.log(cred.user.uid);
            const ID = cred.user.uid;
           
            console.log("Account has been created with user ID:", ID);

            const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "Support Network Member Accounts", ID), {
              firstName: firstName,
              surname: surname,
              contactNo: contactNo,
              email: email,
              password: password,
              confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
              dementiaRelation: dementiaRelation,
              dementiaHubUserID: dementiaHubUserID
            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Support Network Member Account Added Successfully!');
              alert('Account Created Successfully');
              //console.log('Generated identifier:', docRef.id)
              navigation.replace('Login Page');
              })
                        
              })
              .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.message);
              alert(error.code);
              if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
              console.error('Invalid Email or password');
              }else
              console.error('Sorry an error occured');
              });

              }
              catch (e) {
              console.error("Error adding account: ", e);
              }
              }
```

Any help is appreciated!!

I am aware it may be a case of an issue with the formatting of my addDoc, so what am I doing wrong in this? Hard to find an answer online.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this myself! Essentially the whole refferring to the doc was incorrect so I fixed it by doing:

```
try{
          createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
          .then(async (cred) => {
            console.log(cred.user.uid);
            const ID = cred.user.uid;
           
            console.log("Account has been created with user ID:", ID);
            //const dbRef = collection(db, "Support Network Member Accounts");

            const docRef = doc(db, "Support Network Member Accounts", cred.user.uid);

            const data = {
              firstName: firstName,
              surname: surname,
              contactNo: contactNo,
              email: email,
              password: password,
              confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
              dementiaRelation: dementiaRelation,
              dementiaHubUserID: dementiaHubUserID
            };

            setDoc(docRef, data) 
            .then(() => { 
              console.log("Document has been added successfully"); 
              alert('Account Created Successfully');
              console.log('Generated identifier:', cred.user.uid)
              navigation.replace('Login Page');
            }) 
              .catch(error => { console.log(error); })
           
              })
              .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.message);
              alert(error.code);
              if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
              console.error('Invalid Email or password');
              }else
              console.error('Sorry an error occured');
              });

              }
              catch (e) {
              console.error("Error adding account: ", e);
              }
              }
```

Hopefully this helps someone like it helped me!